# Docker support for Azure logging drivers

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose

I know that Docker provides support for sending out the container logs to amazon cloudwatch logs using AWS logging driver. This can be implemented in both `docker run` & `docker-compose.yml` file.
Ref: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/

Since I am new to Azure and want to implement similar functionality for Azure so that it can send the container logs to Azure. After searching a while I found nothing similar to this. Is there any way or any driver/agent available for Azure so that I can implement the similar functionality in my `docker-compose.yml` file?

Answer (score 1):

Their is a Container Monitoring solution but built when used an Orchestrator like K8s, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/containers).

Another one is monitoring Container Groups, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-log-analytics).

Now if you are not using orchestration or Azure Web App for Containers or Azure Container Instances and using a Linux VM to host your containers for example then please try [here](https://medium.com/@stephaniefvisser/monitoring-docker-containers-on-a-stand-alone-linux-host-with-azure-log-analytics-f564b4e21dcc).